# Laravel Grab OTP and Phone From the Link route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In login page I am getting phone number from user and sending a otp code to the number in POST method.
here is my login form button:

```
<button type="submit" formaction="{{url('/client-mobile-login')}}" class="mobile-login__button">CONTINUE
</button>
```

here is my route for it:

```
Route::post('/client-mobile-login', 'ClientLoginController@client_mobile_login');
```

here is my controller function:

```
  public function client_mobile_login(Request $request)
{
 ...otp code here...(otp sending successfully)
 .....
  if($output){
                
  return redirect("otp/".base64_encode($otp).'/'.base64_encode($client_phone1));
           
   }
```

After sending otp I want to view the otp page with encoded otp and phone number on the link.here is my otp route.

```
Route::get('/otp/{otp}/{phone_number}', 'ClientLoginController@get_otp');
```

and here is getotp function

```
  public function get_otp(Request $otp = NULL,$phone_number = NULL){
    

    if ($otp != NULL AND $phone_number != NULL) {
        $data['otp'] = $otp;
        $data['phone_number'] = $phone_number;
        return view('otp',compact('data'));    

    }
}
```

I am getting the link in the address bar but otp page in not rendering

Comment: What do you mean by not rendering? is it just a blank page?

Comment: What are `$data['otp']` and `$data['phone_number']` here?

Comment: You get the blank page for sure, because on your function you redefine `$otp = NULL, $phone_number = NULL` then you check it is `null` or `not null`. And it gives you `null`. And you have no else statement for null.  That's why its return nothing. Hope you got your answer?